# How to populate alt fields with the src of an image for all images on page

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a site that has a page that will have a couple hundred thumbnails.  I would like to have the filenames (the src) of the images populate the alt fields.  So for example, I currently have the thumbnails as follows:

```
<img src="images/thumb1.jpg" />
```

I would like to populate the alt fields with the filename.  So, the desired result would be:

```
<img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="thumb1" />
```

Is there a way I can automatically generate these alt tags using the images src?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you planning to use php, asp.net or any other server side language?

Comment: As of now I only plan on using HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An untested, first guess, would be:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var numImages = images.length;

for (i=0; i<numImages; i++) {
    images[i].alt = images[i].src;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/).

---

Just to demonstrate how much easier this *can* be, with a JavaScript library, I thought I'd also offer the jQuery demo too:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        this.alt = this.src;
        this.title = this.src;
    });
```

[jQuery-based JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/1/).

---

**Edited** because I'm an idiot...

I forgot to point out that you'll need to wait for the window to finish loading (or, at least, for the document.ready event), so try it this way:

```
function makeAlt() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var numImages = images.length;
    for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        images[i].alt = images[i].src;
        images[i].title = images[i].src;
    }
}
```

And change the opening `body` tag to:

```
<body onload="makeAlt">
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/2/).

---

**Edited** to address the OP's final question:

```
function makeAlt() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var numImages = images.length;
    var newAlt, stopAt;
    for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        newAlt = images[i].src.split('/').pop();
        stopAt = newAlt.indexOf('.');
        newAlt = newAlt.substring(0,stopAt);
        images[i].alt = newAlt;
        images[i].title = newAlt;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/3/), though I suspect there's a far more concise way...

Comment: you are using "this" wrong, and need to split out the name from the path and extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was trying something like this earlier, however I just couldn't get it to work.  

I will be giving this a shot now!

Comment: If he just wants the actual filename like his example, he could `images[i].src.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]`

Comment: @Robert Ooo.. I like the use of `.pop()` instead of the way I did it.

Comment: @rob, you're absolutely right (and I caught that in my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/), and corrected here subsequently. Thanks for the catch, though :)

Comment: I added the following, but it still didn't seem to do the trick.  Is there something I'm missing? I've been having one of those days, haha.

`<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var numImages = images.length;
    
    for (i=0; i<numImages; i++) {
        images[i].alt = images[i].src;
        images[i].title = images[i].src;
    }
</script>`

Comment: The code is probably being run before the DOM is ready. Put the script at the bottom of your HTML `body` or run the code in an `onready` event. (Or use a framework to help you!)

Comment: Ah! Facepalm.. Haha, thank you all so much! I appreciate the help, and you saved me from pulling out the rest of my hair.

Comment: Last question.. Is there a way I can show only the filename, and not the path and file extension?

Comment: :) @Hans, indeed so. The section after the third `hr` should address that issue, and provide a [JS Fiddle demo of the same](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZcdSS/2/). Sorry, I'm so used to jQuery nowadays that it never occurred to me... =/

Comment: @Metacom, yep: see the 'final' edit... =b Though I do believe that there are far more concise ways to achieve the same end.

Comment: @Metacom, no problem at all :)

Comment: @Metacom, I'd like to suggest that, if the answers here solved your problem, you might want to accept the answer that best helped you (click the `✓` besides whichever answer that might be), and up-vote those that were also useful to you. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I marked checked the answers that helped, however it won't allow me to upvote.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the file name you could add to David Thomas's code...

```
var name = images[i].getAttribute('alt').split('/');
name = name[name.length-1].split('.')[0];
```

So that you end up with...

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var numImages = images.length;

for (i=0; i<numImages; i++) {
    var name = images[i].getAttribute('src').split('/');
    name = name[name.length-1].split('.')[0];
    images[i].setAttribute('alt') = name;
}
```

(Also amazingly untested)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, with some simple DOM operations and a dash of regex magic:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// This will extract the file name (minus extension) from the image's `src`
// attribute. For example: "images/thumb1.jpg" => "thumb1"
var name_regexp = /([^/]+)\.[\w]{2,4}$/i;
var matches;

for ( i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    matches = imgs[i].src.match(name_regexp);

    if ( matches.length > 1 ) {
        imgs[i].alt = matches[1];
        imgs[i].title = matches[1];
    }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/MuPyb/1/) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var count = images.length;
for (i=0; i<count; i++){
    var src = images[i].getAttribute("src");
    var path = src.split("/");
    var fullname = path[path.length - 1];
    var name = fullname.split(".");
    var result = name[0];
    images[i].setAttribute("alt") = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real questions you should be asking is will all this actually help my SEO, because I assume that is the reason why you would like your alt tags populated?

There is some evidence that Google is getting better at reading Javascript, but will it run the scrip before it crawls the pages and add the alt text then index the page with that alt text and consider that alt text to provide additional value outside of the keywords it already found in your file names, especially considering that it rendered the script so it will probably know that the alt is just being copied form the file name. Or will Google simply index all the html and not even bother trying to run the javascript?

I would be interested to hear any additional insight others may have on this.

I personally feel there is a low probably that this will end up helping your SEO. If you are using a content management system you should probably be looking at how to add alt text via PHP by taking the variable for the page heading or title and inserting that to the alt text.

Unless you don't care about your SEO and are really doing this for text readers, then forget everything i just said.